# How to: Hibernate 3.xx Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

Here is the scenario I have:

5 tables.

Author, Publisher, Region, Medium & Title

Title has foreign keys to all the other tables. I have a list of Title objects and want to create a query on it. There is a many-to-many relationship on it

Can someone help with with some examples or snippet of code on how I would be going about it using Hibernate 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have had a look into the [hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Well here's a basic example:

```
FROM Title AS title JOIN title.Author AS author JOIN title.Publisher AS publisher WHERE author.name LIKE "a%" AND publisher.address LIKE "%Ohio%"
```

It selects all titles who have authors who's name start with "a" and who also have publishers with adresses in Ohio.

It would be best if you look-up the Hibernate documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

and also the different types of joins here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That is HQL or JPQL but not criteria API